# Law of composition

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I understood up to now that the term 'law of composition' was an older alternative to 'binary operation'. But according to [this Wikipedia disambiguation page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition) it is an alternative to 'binary function'. Which is correct? Also, which term is preferred, out of 'law of composition' and 'binary operation', if any?

Comment: Both functions and relations can be composed (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition - there's a paragraph about relations), as long domains and codomains match: if $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$, then $g \circ f: X \to Z$. $f, g$ can be interpreted as either functions in $\bf Set$ or relations in $\bf Rel$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A binary function is a function that takes two inputs and produces an output; a binary operation is the same except that the inputs and output are all supposed to come from the same set.  "Law of composition" is indeed an older term, and I don't recall having seen it used for anything more general than binary operations.  Nevertheless, if someone were to use "law of composition" to refer to a binary function whose inputs and outputs come from different sets, I would not be shocked and would not object; the same applies if someone were to use "law of composition" to refer to a function with more than two arguments.

Comment: Would you then say that "law of composition" is probably too general a term, so in effect it means just the same as function really?

Answer (score 0):

A law of composition on a set $S$ is any rule for combining pairs $a, b$ of elements of $S$ to get another element say,  $p$ of $S$. Some models of this concept are addition and multiplication

Comment: I don't really see how this answers the question.  It is related but perhaps should be left as a comment instead.